# Array value didn't get outside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have to get the main category, child, subchild etc from db. Got the main category and child, but didn't get the subchilds outside of foreach loop.Got the correct value inside of the loop. am using the following code for this...I've declare the $sub_childs = array() just after $children_data = array() but then i got blank page in browswer.. anybody please help. thank u

```
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {$sub_childs = array();
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {

                    $sub_childs = array();
                    $sub_child = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
                    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($children_child);// got the correct values in here
                    foreach ($sub_child as $c_child) {
                        $data = array(
                            'filter_category_id' => $c_child['category_id'],
                            'filter_sub_category' => true
                        );

                        if ($this->config->get('config_product_count')) {
                            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
                            $c_child['name'] .= ' (' . $product_total . ')';
                        }

                        $sub_childs[] = array(
                            'name' => $c_child['name'],
                            'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $c_child['category_id'])
                        );
                    }
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($sub_childs);// here also got it
                    $data = array(
                        'filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    if ($this->config->get('config_product_count')) {
                        $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
                        $child['name'] .= ' (' . $product_total . ')';
                    }

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name' => $child['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
                    echo '<pre>'; print_r($sub_childs);
                }
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($sub_childs);
                // Level 1
                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name' => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'child' => $sub_childs,                  // didn't get here 
                    'column' => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a scope problem, try initializing the variable outside the foreach first:

```
$sub_childs = array();

foreach ($children as $child) {
```

Probably just `$sub_childs;` would work